# Same proguard, works in ant, but failed in gradle

Tags: android, ant, gradle, httpclient, proguard

I have a android project, and it's proguard-project.txt is:

```
-ignorewarnings
-libraryjars libs(*.jar;)

-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }

-keep class org.apache.commons.httpclient.** {*;}
-keep class com.nostra13.universalimageloader.** {*;}
-keep class org.codehaus.jackson.** {*;}
-keep class com.google.zxing.** {*;}
```

When i want to build a apk, i run ant, it builds successfuly, and works fine. But if i run "gradle build", it builds successfully, but the apk can't get any data from network.

When i disable the proguard in build.gradle, the apk that gradle builded works fine.

So , what's the problem? it is the httpclient?

Answer (score 0):

i already found the problem.

It's the org.codehaus.jackson.  This library somehow don't work after builded by gradle. So what i need is to remove jackson, and replace the native JSONObject and JSONArray class in Android.